# use a variable inside input for python27 fails with syntax issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, input

I have the following code which works both in py 27 and 36 :

```
all_config_msgs = ['Okta App URL. E.g https://acme.okta.com/home/amazon_aws/b07384d113edec49eaa6/123: ','Organization username. E.g jane.doe@acme.com: ']
config_details = []
for config_msg in all_config_msgs:
    config_details.append(input(config_msg))
```

In py 36 and 27, I get input prompt :

> Okta App URL. E.g https://acme.okta.com/home/amazon_aws/b07384d113edec49eaa6/123:

- in py 36, I put :

**any_reply**

and it takes it successfully

- in py 27, I put :

**any_reply**

which fails with

```
config_details.append(input(config_msg))
File "<string>", line 1
https://acme.okta.com/home/amazon_aws/b07384d113edec49eaa6/123
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

FYI - In py 27 it works if I put the response as  **"any_reply"**
but I need to have a way of answering without the double quotes/quotes.

I understand in py 27, input is doing an eval but what is a good way to have the input prompt as a variable without getting the above error.

Comment: The Python 2.x equivalent of Python 3's `input()` is `raw_input()`.  2.x `input()` accepts only syntactically valid Python expressions.

Comment: so cant be done in input ?

Comment: @Scooby `input()` in python 2 is something like `exec(raw_input())`, I don't believe a url is standard python tokens (not executable code), so the answer to your previous question is probably "no". You'll need to do what the answer suggested, or manually read from stdin.

Answer (score 5):

On Python 2.7 you should use `raw_input` instead.

If you want to support multiple version of Python you can make your own function that will work on both Python 2 and 3:

```
def my_input():
    try:
        return raw_input()
    except NameError:
        return input()
```

You can also take advantage of [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) library that can help you a lot with compatibility issues:

```
from six.move import input
```

That will use `raw_input` in Python 2 and `input` in Python 3.

Comment: this has to work with both 27 and 36 , so I need to use input.

Comment: Then you can make your own input function that handles both Python2 and 3. I'll provide an example/

Answer (score 1):

Denis' answer is correct. You can conditionally use the function. This is an incredibly common pattern in Python, especially when you're concerned with cross-version compatibility.

```
try:
    my_input = raw_input
except NameError:
    my_input = input

all_config_msgs = ['Okta App URL. E.g https://acme.okta.com/home/amazon_aws/b07384d113edec49eaa6/123: ','Organization username. E.g jane.doe@acme.com: ']
config_details = []
for config_msg in all_config_msgs:
    config_details.append(my_input(config_msg))
```

Tested and working in Python 2.7 and 3.5, but it will work as well for your versions.

Another option that is a bit contested, because some people get all weird about changing global names, is to just enforce that raw_input exists, or define it:

```
try:
    _ = raw_input
except NameError:
    raw_input = input
```

Comment: I would do `try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError: pass` so you can use `input` in your program.

Comment: you don't need to assign anything to `raw_input` in your exception block

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I just added a similar example. Some people get weird about redefining conventionally built in names but I prefer that as well :D

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm not sure what you mean. You should provide your comments as an answer.

Comment: reading all this, now I think it should be closed as duplicate. this issue has been raised a thousand times here all through the years.

Answer (score 1):

you can use
[six library](http://six.readthedocs.io/) for resolving compatibility issues